# Hibernate, Scala and Play

Tags: hibernate, scala, playframework

I can't seem to find any details on using Hibernate with Scala and the Play Framework. There is (limited and incomplete) information regarding doing this with Java, but none with Scala. It's not obvious to me how to set it up within the framework. Are there any specific, recommended steps to accomplish this?

Specifically what I am trying to accomplish:
1. Start up a Hibernate sessionfactory on application start
2. Dependency inject sessionfactory in controllers to use hibernate session

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [template from the Lightbend website](http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/play-hibernate) that will fit your needs. It is indeed in Java but it is easy to adapt it to Scala. You can download it manually or use `activator ui` to instantiate a template from the activator web interface. You can also use the `activator new` command to instantiate one from the CLI.

Your question is too vague to have a "correct answer" though.